# TcpClient.ConnectAsync or BeginConnect/EndConnect in F# async workflow

Tags: asynchronous, f#

[TcpClient.ConnectAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194211.aspx) is a Task, which doesn't work readily with F# async workflows.

I think I'm missing something really simple here -- is there a general way to use either the Async or Begin/End functions from workflows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`Async.AwaitTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837067.aspx) and [`Async.FromBeginEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370564.aspx).

Generally this will work:

```
async {
  ...
  do! client.ConnectAsync(address, port) |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

However, because the `Async` module only works directly with `Task<'T>` and `ConnectAsync` returns `Task`, the code required in this particular case is slightly longer:

```
do! client.ConnectAsync(address, port) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.Ignore
```

or

```
let! _ = client.ConnectAsync(address, port) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
```

Comment: I found that this also works: `do! socket.ConnectAsync(host, port).ContinueWith(ignore) |> Async.AwaitTask`

Comment: Ah, now that you mention it, yeah it does.

Comment: Sorry, removed my comment. It's really a matter of taste. Your solution is probably even more efficient since it doesn't create 3 `Async<_>`s.